# WPF DataGrid Row Header is invisible

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, rowheader

I have WPF-MVVM DataGrid. I want to use the Row Header But it is invisible.
I tried to set it with RowHeaderWidth, but it doesn't have any effect.
Below is my code:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Tours}">
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
    x:Name="tourDataGrid" 
    RowHeaderWidth="27"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Height="360">
```

What is wrong ?

Many Thanks in advance...

Comment: Perhaps, your items source is empty?

Comment: No. It is not empty.

Comment: remove AutoGenerateColumns="False" and you see your items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Tours}">
   <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
    x:Name="tourDataGrid" 

    HeadersVisibility="All"

    RowHeaderWidth="27"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Height="360">
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. My mistake was that I didn't see the row header in VS designer, and I thought that also during runtime it would not exist.